# determine name of running function from eip address?

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [use callback function to report stack backtrace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933697/use-callback-function-to-report-stack-backtrace)

Given a void *eip and an array of struct function symbols that contain the address, symbolic name, and binding of all function symbols in the file, how do I determine the function running at the time of the error?

Comment: @WhirlWind definitely a dupe - same user even.

Comment: On Linux, search for tool named addr2line: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3151779/how-its-better-to-invoke-gdb-from-program-to-print-its-stacktrace/4611112#4611112

Comment: This is not a dup - finding the function name given an ip has nothing to do with a stack or backtrace.

Answer (score 1):

If the executing module isn't relocated at runtime, you could probably try to check if your EIP lies between two function addresses in your function symbols.

Comment: Even if it is relocated, the OS will provide a way to retrieve the relocation offset, and after subtracting this off EIP the same thing can be done.