How do you translate a stack trace / address on Mac so that you can use addr2line?
I am trying to store a stack trace in a form that can later be decoded using addr2line. I get the stacktrace itself via backtrace, but I dont know how to translate this into a positon independent address.
Solutions that I have tried:

I tried passing that into backtrace_symbols as many tutorials suggest. I then get a string like "0   MyExecutable   0x00000001004a2ba1 _Z13EventLoop_addPPvP7Event_s + 97". When I try and pass the address from there "0x00000001004a2ba1" to addr2line addr2line -e MyExecutable 0x00000001004a2ba1 it is unable to return function+line info.
Using the same address as above with atos passing the executable
Using the same address as 1 with atos and pass a processId instead of an executable.

The reason only 3 works is because of ASLR. The answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/63856113/516813 shows how to translate the address on linux, but the solution doesnt work for Mac because dladdr1 doesnt exist and I cant find a way to get the link_map. Does anyone know how to do this for Mac?

atos tool is included by default with Xcode on macOS.If you don't already have Xcode installed
xcode-select --install

is it there??
which atos

rest part
atos -o YourProgram -l <base_addr> <absolute_addr>


atos isnt a valid solution because it requires the process to be running. I need this to work if the process is already dead.
