# What have been done before the entry of user's main function writen in C?

Tags: c++, c, linux, windows

What have been done before the entry of user's main function writen in C?
Are there some differences bettween linux and windows?

As for C++, what are the diffferences?

Comment: Please one question per question

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53570678/what-happens-before-main-in-c

Comment: Please read the description of the tags that you apply to a function. As a new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: @idclev 463035818 I think these questions are related, so i put them together.But, I will follow your advice.Thanks for your help.