# Can glog (c++) print line number in its stacktrace?

Tags: c++, glog, abseil

glog (c++)'s failure signal handler can print stacktrace on segfault etc (see [here](https://hpc.nih.gov/development/glog.html)). Can the stacktrace include line number as well?

Edit:
Even if I use `LOG(FATAL)`, the stacktrace does not have line number.

```
*** Check failure stack trace: ***
    @     0x7f43546debd6  google::LogMessage::Fail()
    @     0x7f43546deb1a  google::LogMessage::SendToLog()
    @     0x7f43546de46b  google::LogMessage::Flush()
    @     0x7f43546e1530  google::LogMessageFatal::~LogMessageFatal()
```

I initializes `glog` as follows

```
  google::InstallFailureSignalHandler();
  google::InitGoogleLogging(argv[0]);
  gflags::ParseCommandLineFlags(&argc, &argv, /*remove_flags=*/true);
```

If you are seeing line numbers, what could I be missing? Thanks!

Comment: Checkout here https://stackoverflow.com/a/19094539/10035556

Comment: Thanks! That seems to be for go? Sorry about the confusion -- I edited the question to clarify.

Comment: Do you mean the `LOG(FATAL)` level? If you do, the log line itself prints the line number so I am not sure what you mean. If you mean just printing the stack trace using glog that is not exposed to the user in the C++ library. (though I think you might be able to define a macro to do it using `FLAGS_log_backtrace_at`, `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` though probably not safe)

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636456/how-to-get-a-stack-trace-for-c-using-gcc-with-line-number-information

Answer (score 0):

There is a fatal message before stack trace.

```
WARNING: Logging before InitGoogleLogging() is written to STDERR   // here
F1015 19:51:48.561210 15798 test.cc:36] []This is a test
*** Check failure stack trace: ***
Aborted (core dumped)
```