# Linux: using backtrace(), /proc/self/maps and addr2line together results in invalid result

Tags: c, linux, elf, backtrace

I'm trying to implement a way to record callstacks of my program into a file then display it later.
Here are the steps:

- Write the content of /proc/self/maps to a log file.

  - In this example, the content of /proc/self/maps is:
  - `00400000-05cdc000 r-xp 00000000 00:51 12974779926     helloworld`
  - Which means the base address of `helloworld` program is 0x400000.
- In the program, whenever an interesting code needs to have its callstack recorded, I use the function `backtrace()` to obtain the callstack's addresses then write to the log file. Let say the callstack in this example is:

  - 0x400001
  - 0x400003
- At some point later, in a separate log viewer program, the log file is opened and parsed. An address in the callstack will be deducted by the base address of the program. In this case:

  - `0x400001 - 0x400000 = 1`
- I then use this deducted offset to obtain the line number using addr2line program:

  - `addr2line -fCe hellowork 0x1`
  - However this produces `???` result, i.e. invalid offset.
- But if I don't deduct the callstack's address, but pass the actual value to add2line command:

  - `addr2line -fCe hellowork 0x400001`, then it returns correct file and line number.

The thing is if the address in within a shared object, then an absolute address won't work while a deducted offset will.

Why is there such a difference in the way the addresses are mapped for the main executable and the shared objects? Or maybe this is `backtrace` implementation specific, such that it always returns an absolute address for a function within the main executable?

Comment: addr2line only recognizes VMA addresses. Like you already found, for shared libs, VMA addresses start @ 0, but for EXEs, they can start @ 0x400000. Here's another explanation with a drawing. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636456/how-to-get-a-stack-trace-for-c-using-gcc-with-line-number-information/63855266#63855266

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why is there such a difference in the way the addresses are mapped for the main executable and the shared objects?

The shared libraries are usually linked at address 0 and relocated. The non-position executable is usually linked at address 0x400000 on `x86_64` Linux and must *not* be relocated (or it wouldn't work).

To find out where a given ELF binary is linked, look at the `p_vaddr` address of the fist `PT_LOAD` segment (`readelf -Wl foo` will show you that). In addition, only `ET_DYN` ELF binaries can be relocated, while `ET_EXEC` binaries must not be.

Note that position-independent executables exist, and for them you need to do the subtraction.

Note that shared libraries are usually linked at address 0 (and so subtraction works), but they don't *have to*. Running `prelink` on a shared library will result in a shared library linked at non-0 address, and then the subtraction you use will not work *either*.

Really, what you need to do is subtract at-runtime load address from linked-at address to get relocation (which would be 0 for non-PIE executables, and non-0 for shared libraries), and then subtract that relocation from the program counter recorded by `backtrace` to get the symbol value.

Finally, if you iterate over all loaded ELF images with [dl_iterate_phdr](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dl_iterate_phdr.3.html), the `dlpi_addr` it provides is *exactly* the relocation that you need to subtract.