# Printing full backtrace in c++

Tags: c++, linux, g++, backtrace

I want to dump a backtrace from a C++ program in Linux in a similar format as it is done in gdb. I tried to use the backtrace() and backtrace_symbols() functions for this purpose. These returned function names and offsets. I can use the __cxa_demangle() function to get a readable function name.

Is there any way to get the file/line positions too, as it is done by gdb?

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636456/stack-trace-for-c-using-gcc which includes a solution in the question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[How it's better to invoke gdb from program to print its stacktrace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3151779/how-its-better-to-invoke-gdb-from-program-to-print-its-stacktrace/4611112#4611112)`

Methode #4, shows a way to get filename and line. But uses a extern program..

Comment: If you don't mind really executing GDB to get a backtrace you can take a look at how the Warzone 2100 project does it. We're basically using a combination of these techniques to get GDB-quality output if possible and progressively fall back to simpler strategies (e.g. if GDB isn't available or libc doesn't provide backtrace()). (the gist of it resides in https://github.com/Warzone2100/warzone2100/blob/master/lib/exceptionhandler/exceptionhandler.cpp )