# C++: Does assert() failure trigger any signals?

Tags: c++, assert

I would like to use this [stacktrace method #4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3151779/how-its-better-to-invoke-gdb-from-program-to-print-its-stacktrace/4611112#4611112) implementation upon assertion failure.

So if there are no signals triggered, could you suggest a way to detect an assertion failure before the executable exits?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On Linux, an `assert`  failure (if not disabled with `-DNDEBUG`) is doing (from `/usr/include/assert.h`)

```
# define assert(expr)                                                   \
  ((expr)                                                               \
   ? __ASSERT_VOID_CAST (0)                                             \
   : __assert_fail (__STRING(expr), __FILE__, __LINE__, __ASSERT_FUNCTION))
```

and the internal [`__assert_fail`](http://glibc.sourcearchive.com/documentation/2.8plus-p20080809-3/assert_8c-source.html) routine is calling `abort`, which sends a `SIGABRT` to the process, which you might catch if you really wanted to.

But a simpler way is to have **your own "assert"-like macro**. This is what many free software (GTK with `g_assert`, GCC with `gcc_assert`, ...) are actually doing.

Comment: tyvm - I will look into gcc_assert

Comment: **No**, `gcc_assert` is only useful for those developing **inside the GCC compiler** (or some GCC compiler plugin), not for GCC users. I mention it only as an example of good practice. Don't use it, but **define your own `kfme4_assert` macro** do to what you want.

Comment: So it sounds like I should just drop that backtrace()/backtrace_symbols() (in the link above) implementation into my own macro.

Comment: Yes, your `kfme4_assert` macro would call a `kfme4_assertfail` function which would do the `backtrace` trick.