# How to get full path to source file in C?

Tags: c, clang, llvm

I know that I can do the following to print the source file from within a C program:

```
printf("__FILE__: %s\n", __FILE__);
```

However, this yields the "path by which the preprocessor opened the file", according to the [docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Standard-Predefined-Macros.html). In this case it gives:

```
__FILE__: common.c
```

I know further that I can use the following [clang feature](https://releases.llvm.org/7.0.1/tools/clang/docs/SanitizerCoverage.html) to print the source file as well:

```
void *pc = __builtin_return_address(0);
char pc_desc[1024];
__sanitizer_symbolize_pc(pc, "%p %F %L", pc_desc, sizeof(pc_desc));
printf("__sanitizer_symbolize_pc: %s\n", pc_desc);
```

Similarly, though, it only prints the relative path:

```
__sanitizer_symbolize_pc: 0x10563a873 in Y common.c:4
```

This is a problem when two files have the same static function (in this case `Y`) on the same line in separate sub-directories, e.g.:

```
__sanitizer_symbolize_pc: 0x10563a873 in Y common.c:4
__sanitizer_symbolize_pc: 0x10563a933 in Y common.c:4
```

Of course the code could be refactored, or the binary matched to the source code after the program runs, or the compilation process could be changed to compile the `common.c` file from a higher-up parent folder. But given this example, how does one get the full path to the source file from the C program itself?

It seems that clang's IR has the directory info preserved [in metadata](http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1DIScope.html#aa15b555d1f611dd569d76097fd969da1), but it is unclear how it is accessed. For example, the `common.ll` file contains the following line:

```
!1 = !DIFile(filename: "common.c", directory: "/full/path/to/subdir")
```

<sub>I am using manually-compiled clang 7.0.1 on Mac OS.</sub>

Comment: If you had compiled all you files in the different subdirectories using one working directory, that normally cmake does, you would have avoided the described problem with the short file names.

Comment: Do you want the filename to be accessed by the pre-compiler, like `__FILE__`, or is it okay if you get it at run-time?

Comment: @NeilEdelman Either way is fine. I think `__sanitizer_symbolize_pc` is already a run-time call, although my guess is that it uses debug symbols from compile-time.

Comment: MacOSX may use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10365086/glibc-function-to-retrieve-current-executable-name.

Comment: @NeilEdelman Thanks! Although it looks like the other question is for getting the executable file's name rather than the source file's name.

Comment: Ahh, I misunderstood the question. `realpath` is not in my MacOS, but see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055671/how-can-i-get-the-behavior-of-gnus-readlink-f-on-a-mac

Answer (score 2):

can consider giving it a full path at compile time?

like the following, call the `realpath` to take a full path

```
SRCS = $(wildcard *.c)
OBJS = $(SRCS:.c=.o)
CFLAGS = -g -Wall
CC = clang
BIN = test

$(BIN) : $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $^ -o $@

%.o : %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $(realpath $<)

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJS) $(BIN)
```