# How to catch SIGSEGV and write in which line it occured

Tags: c

I want to catch `SIGSEGV` signal and write on `stdout` in which line did it occur. I guess i should use `SA_SIGINFO` flag for `sigaction` structure and use `sa_sigaction` instead of `sa_handler` because i get more information about the sginal. When `SIGSEGV` occur in `siginfo_t` structure the field `si_addr` is filled with the address of the fault. What does this mean? Is that address in memory of variable or function that triggered `SIGSEGV`?

I am learning from the book "The linux programming interface" but there is nothing about `sa_sigaction` (only about `sa_handler`), instead i have read about this on man pages.

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<signal.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<limits.h>
#include<errno.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>
#include<sys/types.h>

#define osErrorFatal(userMsg) osErrorFatalImpl((userMsg),__FILE__,__func__,__LINE__)
#define osAssert(expr,userMsg)\
    do{ if(!(expr)) {osErrorFatal(userMsg);} }while(0);

#define MAX_ARGUMENTS 10

void osErrorFatalImpl(char *userMsg,const char *fileName,const char *funcName,const int lineNum)
{
    perror(userMsg);
    fprintf(stderr,"File name: %s\nFunc name: %s\nLine num: %d\n",fileName,funcName,lineNum);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

void signal_handler(int sig, siginfo_t *info, void *ucontext)
{
    fprintf(stdout,"Caught signal '%s'\n",strsignal(sig));
    //now i want to print in which line SIGSEGV occured in child process
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if(argc<2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Error: usage ./a.out file_path\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    char *programPath = NULL;
    osAssert((programPath = realpath(argv[1],programPath)) != NULL, "realpath failed");
    char *programArguments[argc];
    programArguments[0] = strdup(strrchr(programPath, '/'));
    int i;
    for(i=1;i<argc-1;i++)
        programArguments[i] = strdup(argv[i+1]);
    programArguments[i] = NULL;
    int childPid;
    switch((childPid = fork()))
    {
        case -1:    //error
            osAssert(0,"fork failed");
        case 0:     //child branch
            execvp(programPath, programArguments);
            _exit(127);
        default:    //parent branch
        {
            struct sigaction sa;
            sa.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
            sa.sa_sigaction = signal_handler;
            osAssert(sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask) != -1,"sigemptyset failed");
            osAssert(sigaction(SIGSEGV,&sa,NULL) != -1, "sigaction failed");

            wait(NULL);
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        }
    }

}
```

This is the program that is triggering `SIGSEGV` :

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<signal.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<limits.h>
#include<errno.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>
#include<sys/types.h>

#define osErrorFatal(userMsg) osErrorFatalImpl((userMsg),__FILE__,__func__,__LINE__)
#define osAssert(expr,userMsg)\
    do{ if(!(expr)) {osErrorFatal(userMsg);} }while(0);

#define MAX_ARGUMENTS 10

void osErrorFatalImpl(char *userMsg,const char *fileName,const char *funcName,const int lineNum)
{
    perror(userMsg);
    fprintf(stderr,"File name: %s\nFunc name: %s\nLine num: %d\n",fileName,funcName,lineNum);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

void signal_handler_child(int sig)
{
    osAssert( kill(getppid(), sig) != -1,"kill failed");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct sigaction sa;
    sa.sa_handler = signal_handler_child;
    sa.sa_flags = 0;
    osAssert( sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask) != -1,"sigemptyset failed");
    osAssert( sigaction(SIGSEGV,&sa,NULL) != -1,"sigaction failed");
    char *s=NULL;
    printf("%s\n",s);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

I know i can use gdb but i don't want to. I want to make parent process that will look out for his children.

Comment: No, this is the address of the instruction where the fault occurred. If you had debug symbols (the binary is compiled with debug option. `-g` for gcc/clang). You can look that up, find this address and it will point to the filename, line number, which you can then print.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9207599/694576

Comment: you can get easily the address in the child process at witch the error occur from the signal handler. but getting a line in the file will require parsing the debugging symbols.

Comment: Stuff one safely can do in a `SIGSEGV` handler is very limited.  You *might try* [backtrace_symbols_fd](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/backtrace.3.html).

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35325808/backtrace-inside-signal-handler

Comment: You need to be careful with your signal handler.  You can only safely call async-signal-safe functions from within a signal handler. `fprintf()` isn't one of those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the parent process you may not be able to catch `SIGSEGV` that was generated in the child process. What you could do is [waitpid](https://linux.die.net/man/2/waitpid) and use options `WIFSIGNALED` and `WTERMSIG` to get the signal that killed the child. You can lookup for a generated core dump and report that.

Snippet from waitpid doc

```
        w = waitpid(cpid, &status, WUNTRACED | WCONTINUED);
        if (w == -1) {
            perror("waitpid");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

       if (WIFEXITED(status)) {
            printf("exited, status=%d\n", WEXITSTATUS(status));
        } else if (WIFSIGNALED(status)) {
            printf("killed by signal %d\n", WTERMSIG(status));
        } else if (WIFSTOPPED(status)) {
            printf("stopped by signal %d\n", WSTOPSIG(status));
        } else if (WIFCONTINUED(status)) {
            printf("continued\n");
        }
```

Essentially you want the information to be able to debug your application. You can setup your environment to generate a core dump that you can debug later. Run following command to enable code dumps:

```
ulimit -c unlimited
```

This will create a core dump file `core.pid`. You can view it in gdb for seeing backtrace with following command:

```
gdb executable core.pid
(gdb) bt
```

Comment: how is this relevant with my question? I said i don't want to use gdb

Comment: Updated the answer. I am not sure how you can catch a signal that is generated in another process (child). But you can get child's status using the waitpid and related options.

Comment: To have signal handler in the child itself this post may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35325808/backtrace-inside-signal-handler?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: I catch signal in child process and i send it using kill() system call to parent process. When i get signal in parent process i want to see in which line signal triggered. Is there something like __LINE__ macro when errno occur, just for signals?

Comment: Not that I have heard of. I only know that you can get it via gdb. Since, you can only get it using debug symbols.

Comment: @AleksaJovanovic if your queries got answered and you like the proposed answer you can accept the answer.